# seekbar and player in android

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a simple player.
To create a 'connection' between SeekBar and MediaPlayer and I was touched seekbar anywhere where played and Sync seekbar with player. In your opinion, where is the problem?
what can i do ?
If you have an example in this respect share it

my code:

```
public class MediaPlaybackActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     SeekBar seek_bar;
     Button play_button, pause_button;
     MediaPlayer player;
     Handler seekHandler = new Handler();

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        getInit();
        seekUpdation();
    }

    public void getInit() {
        seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);
        play_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        pause_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause_button);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        pause_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.win8);
        seek_bar.setMax(player.getDuration());




       seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek_bar) {

            }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                    if(player != null && fromUser){
                        player.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                    }
                }
        });



    }

    Runnable run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seekUpdation();
        }
    };

    public void seekUpdation() {

        seek_bar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());
        seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.play_button:
            player.start();
            break;
        case R.id.pause_button:
            player.pause();
        }

 }}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is wrong, use ` only for one-liners

Answer (score -1):

Use the below method

```
AudioManager audioManager;
private int maxVolume;
private int curVolume;    
    /**
             * To initialize the seek bar
             */
            private void initialiseSeekBar() {
                audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                curVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mSeekBarVolume.setMax(maxVolume);
                mSeekBarVolume.setProgress(curVolume);
                mSeekBarVolume
                        .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1,
                                    boolean arg2) {
                                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                        arg1, 0);
                            }
                        });
            }
```